# How to prevent logging code from cluttering real code?

Tags: python, logging, coding-style

I am working on some code where half the code seems to be logging and timing various things. I find this clutters up the real code. I was wondering what are the approaches to still logging everything but cleanly separating the logging and real code?

e.g. some block of code could do something as simple as:

```python
for item in files:
    parsed_item = parse_item(item)
```

but to log it could produce a lot more code which clutters up the real code e.g.

```python
folders = 0
files = 0
paid_users = 0
free_users = 0

for item in files:
    parsed_item = parse_item(item)

    if parsed_item['isFolder']:
        folders += 1
    else:
        files += 1

    if parsed_item['isPaidUser']:
        paid_users += 1
    else:
        free_users += 1

logger.info('Parsed: %d folders %d files %d paid users %d free users' % folders, files, paid_users, free_users)
```

Potentially there could be something cleaner where we use a decorator or context manager for the block of code and then do some logging on the `__exit__()` method e.g.

```python
with parse_files_logger() as logger:
    for item in files:
        parsed_item = parse_item(item)
        logger.log(parsed_item)
```

but keen to see if there are cleaner alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the fact that loggers can be passed some other object than a string, and that object's return value from `str(object)` is used to determine the message. Hence:

```
class ParsedItemInfo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.folders = self.files = self.paid_users = self.free_users = 0

    def add(self, item):
        if item['isFolder']:
            self.folders += 1
        else:
            self.files += 1

        if item['isPaidUser']:
            self.paid_users += 1
        else:
            self.free_users += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Parsed: %d folders %d files %d paid users %d free users' % (self.folders, self.files, self.paid_users, self.free_users)
```

and then in your "real code":

```
parsed_item_info = ParsedItemInfo()

for item in files:
    parsed_item = parse_item(item)
    parsed_item_info.add(parsed_item)

logger.info(parsed_item_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition of some logger class (as in your context manager example) seems sensible to me - that way you separate log-dedicated analysis from the code itself.

I would also split the code into many functions/methods doing exactly one (at least from the perspective of logging) thing, then use decorator(s) to log calls of the functions. In case you want to disable logging (e.g. in production version of the code) you may just replace your decorators with dummies (identity functions):

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        result = f(*args)
        logger.log(f.__name__, args, result)
        return result

    return wrapper

def decorator(f): # a dummy
    return f

...

@decorator
def functionToBeLogged(...):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 methods that I use to move code like this out of the way. But they don't really make the code cleaner. As I said they just push code out of the way.

Method 1:
Use parentheses around the line(s) you want to move out of the way

```
folders = 0
files = 0
paid_users = 0
free_users = 0

for item in files:
    parsed_item = parse_item(item)

    if parsed_item['isFolder']:
        folders += 1
    else:
        files += 1

    if parsed_item['isPaidUser']:
        paid_users += 1
    else:
        free_users += 1

(                                        logger.info('Parsed: %d folders %d files %d paid users %d free users' % folders, files, paid_users, free_users)
```

It may not display that well on stack overflow, but by surrounding the log statement in parentheses you can move whatever's to the right of the opening parenthesis wherever you want. The opening parenthesis must conform to the indent order. The closing parenthesis can be wherever you want.
Another example:

```
...some deeply nested code
                   (                                        
logger.info('Parsed: %d folders %d files %d paid users %d free users' % folders, files, paid_users, free_users
)
```

So you can push the log statement as far left or right as you want.

Method 2:
Using semicolon

Say you have some code like this:

```
login()
logger.info('User has logged in')
```

You can take that log statement and move it to the same line as `login()` if you add a semicolon after `login()`.
E.g.

```
login();                                          logger.info('User has logged in')
```

You can push that log statement as far right as you want.
I like this but if in the future the length of the `login()` statement changes it will shift the log which is on the same line.

So situations where you try to put all the logs at an even distance to the right may get shifted when updating code in the future.
So when you have this:

```
validate_password();                 logger.info("checked password")
validate_username();                 logger.info("checked username")
login();                             logger.info("logged in")
```

May end up like this:

```
validate_password(password);                 logger.info("checked password")
validate_username(un);                 logger.info("checked username")
login(username, password);                             logger.info("logged in")
```

I'm not really a huge fan of either, neither am I a huge fan of log statements making my code harder to read.